# Visual work Flow: Display multiple records via Record lookup

Tags: workflow

We have a requirement where in we need to search for duplicate contacts ( based on contact email , first name, last name etc). Once all duplicates are listed to the user , then they can choose the valid one. We were hoping to use flow using Record lookup functionality. 
Is there a way we can do a record lookup and list the resultset in a screen element.

Comment: There are quite a lot of duplication checkers for Salesforce, some for free. May I ask why you want to build your own? This is one I found after a quick Google search, http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IYLlEAO

Answer (score 2):

Well actually there is a way to find all of the duplicate records in flow. You could use this by populating a a Dynamic Choice. You could populate all the records in the picklist that are duplicate. Create a for loop and have them deleted if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Record Lookup element only returns one record, see the implementation guide [here](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_vpm_implementation_guide.pdf). See the Record Lookup section, which says '*The Record Lookup element ultimately returns only the first
record from the filtered results*'.

You might be able to achieve what you want with a Flow ApexPlugin making the query and providing a list back to the Choice display element. Though I suspect your wanting to be code free here.

I am not sure if you are or have searched but there is quite a few duplication checkers / removal tools for Salesforce. Try searching [AppExchange](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?keywords=duplicate%20contact).